# Setting up a domain using WAMP and NameCheap's DNS service

Tags: dns, wamp

So, I've been working on this for far longer than I should be and I'm quite thoroughly perplexed and lost. I apologize if this turns out to be a facile question, but I'm entirely befuddled and very much in need of some guidance.

Earlier today I registered a cheap .info domain on NameCheap just to play around with as I learn webdev. I have WAMP installed on my computer and I've been testing my projects through localhost. I thought it would be a good idea to have a domain at my disposal in order to understand how it works and better test my work.

NameCheap has a complimentary DNS service (not that I entirely understand what DNS is, although I tried), so I'm using that. I direct both the "@" and "www" host names to my IP address, as shown in the below tutorial:

https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/319/78/how-can-i-setup-an-a-address-record-for-my-domain

However, now when I go to the URL of the domain I bought, it confronts me with a login box that seems to be coming from my wifi network. How do I set this up so that it hosts the information in my WAMP server? Thanks in advance for any help, I really appreciate it.

And, as a side-note, what should read (print or online) to better understand the structure of the internet? I've been studying HTML/CSS/Javascript, but I'm not sure where to look for pragmatic and comprehensive information on how the internet works and how to utilize it as a website administrator. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That public IP address is assigned to the router, not to something behind the router / on the local network.

You have to log into your router/wifi box, and "port forward" port 80 to LAN IP of the server. That way, incoming requests for port 80 (HTTP port) are sent to your Server.

There are also a few other steps that might be necessary like having Windows Firewall unblock incoming port 80 requests.